# How to set up Serilog in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, serilog, global-asax

I have configured following from this answer: [Serilog WCF usage without constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70323791/serilog-wcf-usage-without-constructors) , but I still cannot get my logs.
I have installed serilog, along with the serilog file sink, I have also install the autofac.wcf nuget package and created a global.asax file to implement them. View below:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<TestService.Service1>();
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();

        var logFilePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Log/Log.txt");
        builder.Register<ILogger>((c, p) =>
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
                         .WriteTo.File(logFilePath)
                         .CreateLogger();
        }).SingleInstance();

        Log.Information("Application Startup...");

    }
```

Yet even after doing all this, it still does not work. Can someone tell me what is the wrong with this?

Edit #1: I got the log path correctly after checking the debugging, when I debugged the lines it keeps showing this error in the request,response: "this.Request" threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Edit #2: This is what Im assuming is the problem while debugging, [image]

Comment: Have you tried checking if you have write access to the file? Try if solution of this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61262478/9916400

Comment: Yes I tried, I used this code "var logFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Log/Log.txt");", I didnt use Appdata because it showed I needed to add several things. I would like to add as well, when I debugged the lines it keeps showing this error in the request,response: "this.Request" threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Comment: You said the path is "Log/Log.txt", does the "Log" folder exist?

Comment: Yes it does, also I just edited my comment, I wonder if that shows the problem

Comment: Maybe you can try setting Serilog's self log before configuring the logger: SelfLog.Out = Console.Error;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029828/using-serilog-from-within-wcf